# Replacing values in variable

Tags: r, dataframe, replace

I have data in R `schools` which has 94 variables. Out of which I selected 3 variables in a set for analysis:

```
schools_set <- data.frame(schools$Schoolname, schools$SchoolGenderID, and School$)
```

The `SchoolGenderID` is sorted columnwise (1s and 2s) 1 for male and 2 for female. My question is, how can I replace these 1s and 2s with `"Male"` and `"Female"` respectively in the variable `schools$SchoolGenderID` within the same data frame?

Comment: Your code is incomplete. Can you clarify what you meant? In general, this isn't fully clear. Please add a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536) 
for people to work with.

Comment: schools<- data.frame( read.csv("E:AnnualSchoolData.csv", header = TRUE))
schools$SchoolGenderId[schools$SchoolGenderId == "1"]<-"Male"
schools$SchoolGenderId[schools$SchoolGenderId == "2"]<-"Female"
schools_set<-data.frame(schools$SchoolName,schools$SchoolGenderId,schools$SchoolLevelId) This is the full code. retrieving data from .csv file

Answer (score 0):

```
schools$SchoolGenderID[schools$SchoolGenderID == 1] <- "Male"
schools$SchoolGenderID[schools$SchoolGenderID == 2] <- "Female"
```

Or

```
schools$SchoolGenderID <- ifelse(schools$SchoolGenderID == 1, "Male", "Female")
```

Recommending the latter in this particular situation.

Comment: Or `schools$SchoolGenderID = c("Male","Female")[schools$SchoolGenderID]`.

Comment: Both the codes work fine. Can you please tell me how can i sort it now that all male up and then female down in the column as we do in excel.

Comment: `schools[order(schools$SchoolGenderID, decreasing = TRUE), ]`

Answer (score 0):

try the data.table way :)

```
schools = data.table (schools)

schools [ SchoolGenderID == "Male", "SchoolGenderID" := "1"]
schools [ SchoolGenderID == "Female", "SchoolGenderID" := "2"]
schools = schools [order (Schoolname, SchoolGenderID)]
```

The resultant gender column will not be numeric, but character type, as the initial column was character type. If you want a numeric column, then make new columns:

```
schools [ SchoolGenderID == "Male", "SchoolGenderNo" := 1]
schools [ SchoolGenderID == "Female", "SchoolGenderNo" := 2]
```

Comment: No data.table() functions found. It is giving error

Comment: @ImadAhmad update R if you haven't, and add "library (data.table)" somewhere in the beginning of your code

Comment: "Error in library(data.table) : there is no package called ‘data.table’". I downloaded. While loading with library(data.table) gives the above message.

Comment: @ImadAhmad you need to install the package if you don't have it. Type `install.packages ("data.table")` and hit enter, then reload the package (i.e. type `library (data.table)` and hit enter. Perhaps read some introductory materials about packages in R

Comment: I tried install.packages("data.table") but it is still giving the error message. Though i tried with install.packages("data.table", depedencies = TRUE).

Comment: @ImadAhmad it might help to restart R if you're having issues installing packages

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way in `dplyr`

```
library(tidyverse)


schools_set <- schools %>%
                 select(Schoolname, SchoolGenderID) %>% # Make your subset 
                 mutate(
                   school_gender_id = ifelse(SchoolGenderID == 1, 
                                              "Male", "Female")
                 ) %>% 
                 mutate(
                   school_gender_id = as.factor(school_gender_id)
                 ) %>%
                 arrange(school_gender_id) # Order dataframe
```

`mutate` allows you to modify variables and make new ones. Arrange does the work of order. If the order is incorrect you can instead do: `arrange(desc(school_gender_id))`. A `%>%` is a known as a "pipe" and means "after doing this, move on to the next command."

I recommend this tutorial: http://r4ds.had.co.nz/introduction.html
It was written by Hadley Wickham, the creator of R. Very complete and useful introduction to programming in R. It will be much easier and less ad-hoc if you learn `tidyverse`